# Mixing Resources (REST) and Non-Resources

Tags: java, rest

Our server currently serves a REST-ful API that allows the user to CRUD resources as expected.

What happens if we have something that is not a resource, such as helper data? Do we have to stick to the strict REST-ful convention?

For instance, let's say we have dog in a REST-ful API:

```
GET:  /dogs/
GET:  /dogs/:id
POST: /dogs/
PUT:  /dogs/:id
DELETE: /dogs/:id
```

is it okay to add something like:

```
GET: /util/randomNumber/
```

that returns a random number?

It's not really a resource since you wouldn't ever update it, or delete it, and cannot be part of a collection. It's not dependable either since it will change on every hit.

(note, I'm not actually trying to generate random numbers. Just an example).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is ok to have your random number generator method decorated like

```
@GET
@Path("util/randomNumber")
public Response getRandom(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

In a RESTful environment, not every resource needs to have all CRUD operations. It's perfectly legitimate to have a read only non-collection resource.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use some service to do that via GET request.

The [Apigee team](http://apigee.com/about/api-best-practices) discussions shows many interesting ways and standards to work with URLs and resources in RESTful services.

I've read at page 19 of a [e-book](http://apigee.com/about/content/web-api-design) from Apigee, a approach about conversions and I think that will useful for you.

In your case, I think that best way to work on service that generate some random values, is:

```
GET: /util/generateRandomNumber/
```

In this case you identify you action, generate a random number. Or, let's try to do better:

```
GET: /util/generate?type=number
```

In this case you have more flexibility to put another types for generate.

And you can also put some queries parameters, like:

```
GET: /util/generate?type=number&min=0&max=100
```

which will return one number between 0 and 100.

It's my point of view, I hope that I've helped you.